# Windows 7/8 imcompatibility via XNA?

Tags: xna

I have MS Visual Studio 2010 installed on my machine (a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit), and im developing a game in XNA 4.0 with it. I can run the program just fine from the .exe file in the bin directory, and it appears to have no bugs.

But when trying it on Windows 8 64-bit, it just doesn't run. Am I doing something wrong or is XNA suddenly incompatible in this case?

BTW this game has no 3d graphics at all, just 2D stuff, but iirc every texture2D is rendered through the GPU thing as some sort of flat 3D surface, so idk.

Comment: Microsoft XNA is dead. I suggest MonoGame, which is similar (open-source XNA), and works on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: I second the [Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/) suggestion. It's cross-platform and most of what you need is there. Not only is it similar to XNA, it's an Open Source implementation of it so you shouldn't have to change your source code.

Comment: if i used MonoGame, would a windows 8 target machine still need anything? like the framework or Windows Live? Would all target machines need that? or could it just come out as an exe that would run fine?

Answer (score 1):

I recall having the same problem. Uninstalling the Games for windows Live client (if present) then reinstalling, **then after that** intalling XNA framework helped for me.

Comment: are you saying i need the XNA framework on the Windows 8 machine? and the Windows Live Client as well?

Comment: Yes you do and you can only install it without errors if you install the Games for windows live client prior.

Answer (score 0):

As ashes999 pointed, out, Microsoft's official implementation of XNA is now dead; it's not supported on any new Microsoft products (like Windows 8 and Xbox One). However, the MonoGame project is a viable and very active replacement. Use that.